# Google App Engine Datastore Query: addSort is resulting in 500 Internal Server Error when any method is invoked on the List of results

Tags: java, sorting, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-datastore

I have:

```
Query q = new Query("Kind", key).addSort("DateTime", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(30));
```

While I don't get any error when the above code executes, I get `500 Internal Server Error` the moment I call any method on `results`. (I have checked that `results` is not equal to `null`.) For example, I get this error if I call any of the following methods on `results`:

```
results.isEmpty()
results.size()
results.toString()
for (Entity e : results) {...}
```

When I remove `.addSort(param, SortDirection.DESCENDING)` from the first line `Query q = new Query...`, everything works fine except that the results are not sorted.

For your information, I have also added the datastore-indexes for the property `"DateTime"` in `datastore-indexes-auto.xml` as follows:

```
<datastore-indexes>
  <datastore-index kind="Kind" ancestor="true" source="auto">
    <property name="DateTime" direction="desc"/>
  </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

On checking *Datastore Indexes* at Google App Engine admin console, the index is shown with the status `Serving`.

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error and what can I do about it? Secondly, can I sort the `List` of `Entity` using methods in `Collections` framework? If yes, how?

Comment: Out of interest, are there any log entries associated with your 500 Internal Server errors?

Comment: @IanMarshall I never checked the log but when you asked about it, I went to admin console, found the logs and figured that the problem was with the datastore indexes. I tried to describe the problem in a very simplified way in my question but in reality, at different places in the application, I sort the `Kind` entities by different properties including `DateTime` and other properties. Mistakenly I had created multiple `<property name="MoreProperty" direction="desc"/>` entries in one `<datastore-index>`. I corrected that by creating a different `<datastore-index>` for each property and it...

Comment: ...works now! Thank you very much for your hint!!

Comment: Now, the other potential issue I see is that I have an index with three different properties `DateTime`, `Property2` and `Property3`. Do you think I should vacuum this index or else at some point (as the number of entities increase with use of the application) the `put` operation on `datastore` might result in `IllegalArgumentException` (`"Too many indexed properties"` or `"Index entries too large"`)? Or can I just leave that index with the three properties in `Serving` status without worrying about it?

Comment: I'm not an expert on your potential `IllegalArgumentException`s. This exception could be a reason to vacuum your indices. I suppose the "when" of your vacuuming depends on the criticality of your app, and how sure you are that the surplus indices will never be used. By the way, have you tried the automatic index generation functionality of the dev app server? That way, you could code a test to exercise all your datastore queries, so that all the indices you will need get generated automatically. Then you can store the indices for deployment-time.

Comment: Oh, and you're very welcome for my hint! I find that "2 minds make 3", even if the 2nd mind is just saying something that gets the 1st mind to thinking in a slightly different way and thus to solve the problem at hand.